# android: imap for icloud

Tags: android, jakarta-mail, imap, icloud

I am trying to add an icloud account . I am using javamail . Outgoing connection is working. But incoming testing is failing

IMAP (Incoming Mail Server) information:
Server name: imap.mail.me.com
Security type: Select SSL
Port: 993
Username:myid@icloud.com
Password: Your iCloud password

```
props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", sProtocol);
        props.setProperty("mail." + sProtocol + ".host", acct.sIncomingHost);
        props.setProperty("mail." + sProtocol + ".port",
                acct.sIncomingHostPort);

        props.setProperty("mail." + sProtocol + ".timeout", "30000");
        props.setProperty("mail." + sProtocol + ".connectiontimeout",
                "30000");


        if (acct.iIncomingHostEncryption == Constants.ENCRYPT_TLS) {
            Log.i(TAG, "STARTTLS...");
            props.put("mail." + sProtocol + ".starttls.enable", "true");

            props.setProperty("mail." + sProtocol + ".ssl.trust", "*");
            props.setProperty("mail." + sProtocol
                    + ".ssl.socketFactory.class",
                    "com.myproject.SEMPSSLSocketFactory");
            props.setProperty("mail." + sProtocol
                    + ".ssl.socketFactory.fallback", "false");

        } else if (acct.iIncomingHostEncryption == Constants.ENCRYPT_SSL) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Enable SSL...");
            props.put("mail." + sProtocol + ".ssl.enable", "true");



        }
```

it is working for gmail / yahoo account. I think the properties set need to be changed . Please help me to solve this.

I am getting 
09-30 15:09:25.249: W/System.err(1095): idg.javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: [AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] Authentication failed
09-30 15:09:25.249: W/System.err(1095):     at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:663)

My credential are correct because mail is send successfully to this account using smtp . Getting this checking incoming host

Comment: So how does it fail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it worked with the following properties

props.put("mail." + sProtocol + ".starttls.enable", "true");

```
            props.setProperty("mail." + sProtocol + ".ssl.trust", "*");
            props.setProperty("mail." + sProtocol
                    + ".ssl.socketFactory.class",
                    "com.myproject.MySSLSocketFactory");
            props.setProperty("mail." + sProtocol
                    + ".ssl.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
```

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the [socket factory stuff](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes), then post the [debug output](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug).